# Как в discord.py удалить определённую реакцию на сообщении?

Tags: бот, discord, delete

Есть функция on_raw_reaction_add для проверки добавления реакции, в ней хочу реализовать возможность каждому пользователю добавлять только одну реакцию. То есть, если пользователь добавил реакцию, ещё одну он добавить не может. Хотел просто удалять реакции, если пользователь уже поставил реакцию, но в документации нашёл только через класс discord.Message использовать remove_reaction, но не разобрался как его использовать в функции. Может есть другие способы решения данной проблемы, или можете привести пример использования remove_reaction внутри on_raw_reaction_add?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что это делается очень просто:

```
await bot.http.remove_reaction(channel_id,message_id,emoji,membe_id)
```